# Crash when destroying bodies

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, native-code, physics-engine

When I destroy an object made of several bodies connected by joints, my application crashes without an error. Of course I did some research and found that this happens when one destroys bodies while the physics engine calculates a step. So I just add the bodies to a list and destroy them in onUpdate(), but that didn't help. The funny thing is that destroying simple bodies works like a charm even outside onUpdate() and never ever caused a crash.

There was no error output, just once I managed to catch one saying that the problem is a NullPointerException in World.java on line 507. Surprisingly, there I found the following:

```
public boolean isLocked()
    {
        return jniIsLocked( addr );
    }
```

Could someone tell me what could be going on? I even went so far as to destroy the bodies one at a time:

```
if (!destroyList.isEmpty()){
    Body b = destroyList.get(0);
    destroyList.remove(0);
    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(b);
}
```

The problem persists though.

Notes: The object I am destroying is made of several bodies connected by WeldJoints to one central body. The bodies overlap, so I use negative groupIndex to prevent them from colliding with each other. Removing all the joints associated with a particular body before removing it does not help.
Error output:

```
05-31 15:32:02.486: W/dalvikvm(927): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
05-31 15:32:02.497: W/dalvikvm(927):              in Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;.jniStep (JFII)V (CallBooleanMethodV)
05-31 15:32:02.497: W/dalvikvm(927): Pending exception is:
05-31 15:32:02.506: I/dalvikvm(927): Ljava/lang/NullPointerException;:
05-31 15:32:02.526: I/dalvikvm(927):    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.contactFilter(World.java:507)
05-31 15:32:02.526: I/dalvikvm(927):    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
05-31 15:32:02.536: I/dalvikvm(927):    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:298)
...
```

Comment: Do you still get the problem if you destroy only the joints? You could also check out World.java:507 too :)

Comment: For the third time, yes, I have tried destroying the joints. I have also looked at World.java:507. Both is written in the question :-)

Comment: The question says "Removing all the joints associated with a particular body before removing it does not help". I was asking if you had tried destroying ONLY the joints (and leaving the bodies).

Comment: I see. I haven't tried that yet. I expect that this will work without trouble as the engine crashed long (in terms of the computer) after the joints were destroyed.

Comment: I just tried and removing all joints does not cause the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to first remove the physics connector also and you have to do all this thing into the update method.
So, the remove sequence is
1. Remove joints from the body
2. Remove physics connector
3. Destroy body from the world
and other necessary thing you have to manage manually that I was not mentioned.

EDIT : I found another thing for you. You have to implement runnable handler to destroy body and joints. The following code work for me where I saw how to delete body.

```
dRunnableHandler.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // destroy the bullet body
            PhysicsConnector physicsConnector = gameObject
                    .getPhysicsWorld().getPhysicsConnectorManager()
                    .findPhysicsConnectorByShape(Bullet.this);
            gameObject.getPhysicsWorld().unregisterPhysicsConnector(
                    physicsConnector);

            gameObject.getPhysicsWorld().destroyBody(bulletBody);
            particleSystem.setParticlesSpawnEnabled(false);

            gameObject.getEngine().getScene().detachChild(Bullet.this);

            gameObject.removeBulletCounter++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I haven't tried destroying the physics connector, but that certainly shouldn't crash the physics engine. I will try that when I have the time.

Comment: Well, destroying the connector does not crash the game.

Comment: Thank you, it seems we are getting somewhere. Now it fails with NullPointerException at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.destroyBody(World.java:154). The corresponding line contains this: this.bodies.remove( body.addr );

Comment: The body you want to delete check that it was null or not. I think that thing remaining.

Comment: It seems that sometimes the bodies were indeed null. I added a condition that checks them before trying to remove and it suddenly works. What worries me though, is that I have no idea WHY the bodies can be null. I hate it when I don't understand how my own code works. Anyway, thanks a lot for the effort Siddharth, I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: The underlying problem is still there, I had the application crash on me a couple of times, but only after destroying about 40 bodies.

Comment: Addition: I think I haven't changed anything and the problem disappeared forever. I was unable to reproduce it afterwards.

Comment: My provided approach also does not worked when you have many bodies to destroy because at that time many threads are created and the device or emulator does not handle it.

Answer (score 1):

It´s just an idea, but maybe yo should destroy joints before destroying bodies.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help. See the last paragraph.